# Comparing FFTs to deduplicate IVR recordings

Tags: python, beginner, numpy, audio, signal-processing

I've got a Python script that traverses two file trees, checking all .wav files for duplication.

I'm still an undergrad, and have never worked with audio before.  I'm not entirely sure this is going to be a valid comparison.

I lost the SO answer I was using as a guideline, but the general idea is to split the audio into chunks, FFT those chunks, then compare the results.

I also would appreciate any structure/style advice.

Note: All Olympus Recordings are valid, but I need to load them to have the ffts to compare.

```
import os
import os.path
import wave
import numpy
import struct
from shutil import copy
from subprocess import call, Popen, PIPE

oly_path = "/home/will/Desktop/soundfiles/Olympus Recordings"
titan_path = "/home/will/Desktop/soundfiles/TITAN Recordings"
wav_roots = [oly_path, titan_path]
destination_path = "/home/will/Desktop/soundfiles/output"
temp_wav_path = "/home/will/Desktop/soundfiles/temp.wav"

similarity_threshold = 95
validated_wavs = {}
bunk_wavs = {}

def get_fft_similarity(fft1, fft2):
        hits = 0
        len1 = len(fft1)
        len2 = len(fft2)
        limit = (len1 if len1<len2 else len2)

        if limit == 0:
                return 0

        for i in xrange(limit):
                if (fft1[i] == fft2[i]).all():
                        hits += 1

        ratio = float(hits)/limit
        return int(ratio*100)

def sort_wav(to_sort):
        key = to_sort.filename
        if "Olympus" in to_sort.source:
                while key in validated_wavs:
                        to_sort.generate_new_name()
                        key = to_sort.filename

                validated_wavs[key] = to_sort
                return 1

        if key in validated_wavs:
                if get_fft_similarity(to_sort.fft, validated_wavs[key].fft) >= similarity_threshold:
                        bunk_wavs[key] = to_sort
                        return 0

                while key in validated_wavs:
                        to_sort.generate_new_name()
                        key = to_sort.filename

        for w in validated_wavs.values():
                if get_fft_similarity(to_sort.fft, w.fft) >= similarity_threshold:
                        bunk_wavs[key] = to_sort
                        return 0

        validated_wavs[key] = to_sort
        return 1

def get_fft(fft_path):
        return_list = []
        frames_list = []
        chunk_size = 36
        start = 0
        wav = wave.open(fft_path, 'r')
        frames = wav.readframes(wav.getnframes())
        wav.close()

        while start+chunk_size < len(frames):
                data = struct.unpack(">fdddd", frames[start:start+chunk_size])
                frames_list.append(data)
                start += chunk_size
                if len(frames_list) >= 1000:
                        return_list.append(numpy.fft.fft(frames_list))
                        frames_list = []

        return return_list

def ensure_encoding(encoding_path):
        command = ["soxi", "-e", encoding_path]
        command_proc = Popen(command, stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
        encoding = command_proc.communicate()[0].rstrip()

        if encoding != "Signed Integer PCM":
                call(["sox", encoding_path, "-e", "signed", temp_wav_path])
        else:
                copy(encoding_path, temp_wav_path)

def validate(validate_path):
        ensure_encoding(validate_path)
        ivr_wav = IVR_Wav(validate_path)
        return sort_wav(ivr_wav)

class IVR_Wav:
        def __init__(self, source):
                self.source = source
                self.destination = destination_path + source.split("/")[-1]
                self.size = os.path.getsize(source)
                self.fft = get_fft(temp_wav_path)
                self.filename = os.path.split(source)[-1]

        def generate_new_name(self):
                name = os.path.split(self.source)[-1].replace(".wav", "")
                directory = os.path.split(self.source)[-2].split("/" if "/" in self.source else "\\")[-1]
                self.filename = "".join([name, "_", directory, ".wav"])

                self.destination = os.path.join(destination_path, self.filename)

def main():
        valid = 0
        total = 0
        for wav_root in wav_roots:
                for root, dirs, files in os.walk(wav_root):
                        for f in files:
                                if f.endswith("wav") and os.path.getsize(os.path.join(root, f)) > 16:
                                        total += 1
                                        temp_path = os.path.join(root, f)
                                        valid += validate(temp_path)
                                print "\r", valid, "/", total, " valid::::::", len(validated_wavs),

main()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**UPPERCASE for constants**

As a convention, in Python constants are uppercase:

```
OLY_PATH = "/home/will/Desktop/soundfiles/Olympus Recordings"
TITAN_PATH = "/home/will/Desktop/soundfiles/TITAN Recordings"
WAV_ROOTS = [oly_path, titan_path]
DESTINATION_PATH = "/home/will/Desktop/soundfiles/output"
TEEMP_WAV_PATH = "/home/will/Desktop/soundfiles/temp.wav"
```

**No need for temporary variables**

```
    len1 = len(fft1)
    len2 = len(fft2)
```

Are useless because you use them only once, thus leading to no efficiency gain and code clutter.

```
def get_fft_similarity(fft1, fft2):
        hits = 0
        limit = (len1 if len(fft1)<len(fft2) else len2)

        if limit == 0:
                return 0

        for i in xrange(limit):
                if (fft1[i] == fft2[i]).all():
                        hits += 1

        ratio = float(hits)/limit
        return int(ratio*100)
```

Also about this function:

- `float(hits)/limit` you can remove `float` if you `from __future__ import division`
- Down below:

  ```
   for i in xrange(limit):
              if (fft1[i] == fft2[i]).all():
                      hits += 1
  ```

You are using explicit indexing and a counter variable. Maybe `zip` is and `sum` will simplify your code.

**Use more constants**

You already use some, and that is nice, but things like:

- `"Olympus"`
- `".wav"`
- `"Signed Integer PCM"`
- `"soxi"`
- ...

Should be in their own named constant.

**Are you sure of your class?**

Usually if a class has `init` and only one other function, maybe you can use just a function for simplicity: I am looking at `class IVR_Wav`

**Peculiar *double effect* `sort_wav`**

I noticed that `sort_wav` both modifies a global variable and returns 1 or 0. It is then called by `validate`. Maybe you could write a `validator_helper` to make the check and another function to update the dictionary.

Comment: Thanks for all the feedback, just what I was looking for!  I like the class, am planning on sorting the wavs, then iterating over validated_wavs.values to record the IVR_Wav.destination in a csv wherever the IVR_Wav.source appears.  Is this better done during sort_wav()?  Then store only the FFTs for comparison?

Comment: @Will I would do it the most straigthforward way possible, In/Output will take 95% of the time, so using two passes and two separate functions seems best to me.

Comment: @Will I am so curious about `">fdddd"`, can you explain me what it means? (And then put it  in a constant)

Comment: ">fdddd" is apparently specifying little endian, a four byte-float, and four eight-byte doubles (all signed).  I chose this format because it was a way to unpack the frames into 36-byte chunks.  I ran `getsizeof(frames[0])` to get 36 bytes per frame.  Is this correct?

Comment: @Will It's exactly because I have no idea that I asked, so I can't confirm you that it is correct :) (By the way, if the matter is so complicated also add a comment near that string).